# Datwarehousing queries

Tags: data-warehouse

I have an interview coming up for the role of a data engineer.
Can someone please help me with some resources for complex queries which are used in datawarehouse
eg: querying two fact tables and other complex queries like this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Good start point is http://www.kimballgroup.com/

if this work will be with MS SQL Server - good point https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/virtuallabs